# Controlling order hue is drawn in seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working with a facetgrid pointplot graph, and have a palette of four colors. They keep drawing lightest to darkest, so dark always covers light. How do I control which color is first drawn? (Sometimes I want the medium toned on top, other times light, etc.)

EDIT
For an MVE:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")

g = (g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w").add_legend())
```

from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

I can't share my data and it's time consuming to exactly replicate it, this is similar enough.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Maybe with `hue_order=` to tell the order of the elements of the `hue=` column? And `palette=['color1', 'color2', ...]` to tell the order of the colors?  Maybe also add `alpha`?